# How to convert date formats in excel (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula, format

I have a autogenerated report that has some formatting on dates I need updated from dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS am/pm. Sometimes the data also does not have the seconds and it I do need the data to read at least 00 on the seconds. I am unsure if VBA or a enhanced formula is needed here due to the variance of times generated with and w/o SS.

I tried =TEXT(F2,"DD/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); however it did not work on the las to entries, it kept it as 15/11/2020 10:20 PM

[image]

Comment: Seems like the last two rows are text, not datetimes.

Comment: Try the formula `=TEXT(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(F2),F2)+IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(F2),F2),"mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss am/pm")`